# Is an NSFileWrapper package similar to a Mac OS X Package (pkg)?

Tags: ios, nsfilewrapper

In numerous [places](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/CreateCustomDocument/CreateCustomDocument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH8-SW2), the Apple documentation talks about packages of files (e.g. for iCloud) created by NSFileWrapper.  Is this is any way similar to the .pkg format used to hide a folder as a single file on the OS X platform?

I have an app with multiple text files that I'd like to be able to let the user backup.  I've used NSFileWrapper to create a single 'file' that does this.  I had assumed that this was similar to a .pkg file on OS X, but despite then bringing the file into OS X (via email) I have no way of opening it - despite renaming files, etc.

So, is the NSFileWrapper 'package' completely different to the OS X 'package'?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. One works on the filesystem level, while the other is a bunch of files compressed together with a specirfic set of unpacking instructions

NSFileWrapper, From the link you mentioned:

> A file wrapper is a runtime representation of a file-system node, which is either a directory, a regular file, or a symbolic link.

While a `.pkg` would look something like:

> A xar-based format used on a number of platforms to install files.

Wikipedia, [(un)surprisingly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pkg) enough, has a decent overview of what exactly a .pkg is.